# Captcha not visible in login form

Tags: 7, captcha

I enabled the Captcha module in drupal 7.It is not visible at `user_login`and validation message is shown for not filling it. I tried inspecting it and none appeared.

```
Math question field is required.
```

The password reset form, user registration form has the captcha and are visible too.

What could be the problem?

[image: no captcha shown but validation occurs]

Comment: how is your `$form` rendered in the `user-login.tpl.php` ?

Comment: @berramou, it is normal, there are no edits done to that file.